# array and loop (java)

Tags: java, arrays

```
for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        for(int k=j;k<n;k++){
            if(array[j]>array[k]){
                int temp = array[k];
                array[k]=array[j];
                array[j]=temp;

            }

            }
        }
```

//How does it works? I mean I solved but I am still confused.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bubble sort. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort for an explanation of this simple approach to sorting data.